# Django Unittest for form with password

Tags: django, django-unittest

I want to create a unit test in django testing a form while passing some initial data to it and see if it's valid or invalid. The problem is the framework doesn't allow you to set initial value to a password field, is there any other way around this other than subclassing (which I want to avoid...just for a password field)? My code is below.

```
def test_new_user_joining(self):
    form_data = {
        'full_name': #invalid value,
        'email': 'test_email@gmail.com',
        'password': 'password'
    }
    form = SignupForm(initial=form_data)
    if form.is_valid():
        self.fail('Form should not be valid')

    form_data['full_name'] = # valid value
    form = SignupForm(initial=form_data)
    if not form.is_valid():
        self.fail('Form should be valid')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you just have to use a *data* arg instead of *initial*:

```
def test_new_user_joining(self):
    form_data = {
        'full_name': #invalid value,
        'email': 'test_email@gmail.com',
        'password': 'password'
    }
    form = SignupForm(data=form_data)
    if form.is_valid():
        self.fail('Form should not be valid')

    form_data['full_name'] = # valid value
    form = SignupForm(data=form_data)
    if not form.is_valid():
        self.fail('Form should be valid')
```

Comment: *Initial* is used to set default values for form's fields.